# How to get HTML-INPUT-EMAIL using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have input:

```
<input ng-model="email" type="email" id="form-email" name="email" placeholder="Inter email" maxlength="250">
```

When I enter so long hosting:

```
fax@test.cooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooom
```

I have:

```
$scope.email // undefined
document.getElementById("form-email").value //fax@test.cooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooom
```

But when I enter

```
fax@testooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooh.com
```

I have

```
$scope.email // fax@testooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooh.com
```

How to fix this trouble?

Comment: The first long domain is not a valid email adress so angular doesn't get it's value.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with that, the first email is invalid and the second one is valid that's why it is accepted.

> **Each domain name consists of two parts.**
>
> ***Top Level Domain*** -  A top-level domain (TLD) is the part of the domain
>   name located to the right of the dot. The most common top-level
>   domains are .COM, .NET, and .ORG. Some other popular top-level domains
>   are .BIZ, .INFO, .NAME and .IN etc.
>
> ***Second Level Domain*** - . The second-level domain name is the part of
>   the domain name located to the left of the dot.
>   Steps-to-make-your-own-website is the second-level domain name and
>   represents the organization or entity behind the internet. Second
>   Level Domain name must be registered with an Internet Corporation for
>   Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN)-accredited registrar.

*Why is the 1st email invalid?*

- Because it doesn't contain a valid top-level domain.

Here are the list of Internet Top-Level-Domains:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

*Why is the 2nd email vaild?*

- Cause it contains both valid Top Level and Second Level Domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate email input with the ngPattern directive combined to pattern:

```
<input type="email"
   ng-model="email"
   id="form-email"
   placeholder="Inter email" 
   maxlength="250"
   name="myeamail"
   pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$"
   >
```